# Erro "RequestError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain" ao tentar instalar Electron js

Tags: node.js, front-end, npm, electron

Fala galera!!
Estou tentando instalar o Electron js com o comando npm install electron e está apresentando erro

O erro apresentado ao tentar instalar o electron é o seguinte:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Users\lucas.diniz\Documents\Cursos\Alura\Projeto_electron\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Users\lucas.diniz\Documents\Cursos\Alura\Projeto_electron\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:530:35)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
npm ERR!     at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lucas.diniz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T17_01_20_837Z-debug-0.log
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre o erro, fiz as recomendações sugeridas mas nenhuma deu resultado.
Os comandos que já tentei foram os seguintes:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install electron --strict-ssl=false
npm set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 serverless | npm install electron
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!!

Comment: tenta npm i electron -g